# Unable to fetch TableName Serverless Framework: Missing required key 'TableName' in params

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I followed this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXB2Nv9ygQc&t=2520s) first to try and develop a serverless rest api using serverless framework. It gave an error of MissingRequiredParameter and initialised table name to undefined.

To alleviate that, I found a similar code on [GitHub](https://github.com/cypherkunp/lambda-kittens-app) but deploying this also gives the same error.

Here are the console logs in cloud watch:

```
2021-06-19T23:12:12.606Z    97a3c3b8-375b-4e12-9b89-7ad1e44f1873    INFO    Error saving the kitten to the DB:  MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'TableName' in params
    at ParamValidator.fail (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:61:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
    at ParamValidator.validate (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at callNextListener (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9
    at finish (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9 {
  code: 'MissingRequiredParameter',
  time: 2021-06-19T23:12:12.603Z
}



2021-06-19T23:12:12.606Z    97a3c3b8-375b-4e12-9b89-7ad1e44f1873    DEBUG   putParams:  { TableName: undefined, Item: { name: 'Fluffy', age: 4 } }
```

It gives an error 502 Bad Gateway

serverless.yaml file

```
service: lambda-kittens-app

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs12.x

iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
          - dynamodb:PutItem
          - dynamodb:Scan*
          - dynamodb:GetItem
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/${self:service}-kittens-${opt:stage}

environment:
    DYNAMODB_KITTEN_TABLE: ${self:service}-kittens-${opt:stage}
functions:
    create:
        handler: handler.createKitten
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /v1/kitten
                  method: post
    list:
        handler: handler.listKitten
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /v1/kitten
                  method: get
    get:
        handler: handler.getKitten
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /v1/kitten/{name}
                  method: get
    update:
        handler: handler.updateKitten
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /v1/kitten/{name}
                  method: patch
    delete:
        handler: handler.deleteKitten
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /v1/kitten/{name}
                  method: delete
resources:
    Resources:
        kittensTable:
            Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
            Properties:
                TableName: ${self:service}-kittens-${opt:stage}
                AttributeDefinitions:
                    - AttributeName: name
                      AttributeType: S
                KeySchema:
                    - AttributeName: name
                      KeyType: HASH
                BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
Plugins:
    - serverless-pseudo-parameters
#  Outputs:
#     NewOutput:
#       Description: "Description for the output"
#       Value: "Some output value"
```

Changes made to db-handler.js

```
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

NOTE: I did check several solutions but none of them seems to work.

Comment: Run `sls config` and check the output.

Comment: ```config ........................ Configure Serverless
config credentials ............ Configures a new provider profile for the Serverless Framework
config tabcompletion install .. Install a <tab> completion for chosen shell
config tabcompletion uninstall  Uninstall a <tab> completion
    --autoupdate .......................Turn on auto update mechanism (turn off via "--no-autoupdate")
    --help / -h ........................Show this message
    --version ..........................Show version info```

Comment: The error message is a stack trace coming from your lambda function. Please update your question with the source code where you attempt to write to dynamoDB. `TableName` is undefined there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your application code, I can't be certain.
However I presume you are doing something like this:

```
const documentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ params: { TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_KITTEN_TABLE } });

... // Put call
```

I noticed in your `serverless.yml`, the `environment:` block is at the root level. That won't work, so your environment variable is undefined/not set.

The `environment` block goes inside the `provider` block, or inside the `function` block (depending on if you want to set an env var per function, or for all functions in your stack):

```
provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs12.x
    environment:
      DYNAMODB_KITTEN_TABLE: ${self:service}-kittens-${opt:stage}
```

Comment: Sure thing! No problem

Answer (score 2):

The error msg says that you are using `Tablename`, not `TableName`.

Comment: I updated that but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with tableName. I resolved it using proper tableName.
My code looked like this:

```
const tableName = process.env.COURSE_TABLE;
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const saveParams = {
        TableName:tableName
    }
};
```